# Preventing Jupyter notebook from disconnecting

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, localhost

I have a server I connect to with ssh. Inside this server there are several nodes (virtual machines). I run jupyter notebook inside one of these nodes. The steps I follow in order to run the graphic interface on my local browser are the following:

1. On the node (VM): `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8886 --ip=127.0.0.1`
2. On server: `ssh -N -L 8887:127.0.0.1:8886 node`
3. On local: `ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:8887 server@x.x.x.x`

In particular, inside the node and the server I firstly run `screen` and then I detach, so they will run without problems.
Instead, my problem is in local. If I go away from keyboard for a bit of time It happens that my local instance disconnects, while the processes (training of Neural Networks) on the node of the server are still running as well as the `jupyter notebook --no-browser`
How can I prevent jupyter notebook from disconnecting in local?

Comment: It sounds like the tunnel isn't the problem, but have you tried `nohup` in there? See [here](https://gist.github.com/33eyes/e1da2d78979dc059433849c466ff5996). Do you have some sleeping set up on your computer? How long do you have to go away for it to trigger? How long is the bit of time? Is it super consistent. I find my tunnel from my institution to be more randomly unstable than when I am working at home.

Comment: Also, are you losing anything by it disconnecting? I see you are using screen and detaching? So notebooks run okay? Or does that just mean the notebook server continues running when detached. I can suggest better options for notebooks that you need to be long running if you are losing things when it disconnects.

Comment: I am going to test `nohup`, i did not known it. Yesterday I used screen also on my computer, and it did not disconnected. Basically notebook server continues running when detached, however it is with `--no-browser` option, so I need to run local to see the notebook. And the problem was in local that at a certain point it stopped printing results, although kernel was connected

Comment: You may be better off going into the screen and kicking off your notebook running from the command line with papermill or other options spelled out [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/run-ipynb-on-a-remote-workstation-so-that-all-results-will-be-save-in-the-same-pynb/13340/2?u=fomightez). Then get out of your screen and let it run. (Certain views that rely on active javascript like adjustable widgets won't work that way but maybe you don't have any of those?) This way you aren't reliant on maintaining a connection over a very long time.